# How to handle exception in IAuthenticationFilter interface?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have `created custom Authentication class` using `IAuthenticationFilter interface`.

instead of using `ChallengeAsync` I have directly throw exception how to handle it ?

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
    AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;
    if (authorization == null)
    {
           throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,"FAIL"));
    }


public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        //var challenge = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic");
        //context.Result = new AddChallengeOnUnauthorizedResult(challenge, context.Result);
        //return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

but how to handle exception throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) The HttpResponseException type is a special case, because it is designed specifically for returning an HTTP response.
 So you do not need to handle this exception. From ChallengeAsync code, I suppose you want to add authentication header to response if request was unauthorized. You can implement it like

```
public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
    var challenge = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic");
    var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "FAIL");
    response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(challenge);
    throw new HttpResponseException(response);
}
```